# I don't have permission to access this device on iftop and need to be root to run NetHogs

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, ifconfig

I have two dilemma's here:

One is, I tried using iftop but it said I don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: operation not permitted) I can use ifconfig just fine.

Also, I installed NetHogs and tried to use it. But it came up with, `you need to be root to run NetHogs`.

I'm extremely new to ubuntu, anyone help?

Comment: You can use sudo to run programs with elevated (root) privileges. Example sudo iftop

Comment: iftop needs to be run as root as Nischay says, so sudo iftop it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sudo or gksu

```
$ sudo nethogs
```

or

```
$ gksu nethogs
```